# apache camel routing queues issue

Tags: spring, routes, apache-camel, activemq-classic, message-queue

I'm trying to create an application that gets information from a browser and drops it in a queue. That data is then picked up from the queue and sent through an application for security. The security app should drop it in a different queue when it is done to be picked up by a separate action application.

Could anyone help me along with the routing? Basically, the route I'm looking for is:

Browser/UI -> Qnonsecure -> security app -> QSecure -> action app

What I understand now is the following:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="jms:queue:QnonSecure"/>
        <to uri="jms:queue:QSecure"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

How Can I change this to route to and from applications.
 How do I send the input from the browser into QnonSecure? Also, where in my code do I call the security app between the QnonSecure and QSecure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one possible solution. Take the following route as a starting point:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="restlet:http://localhost:8081/myApp?restletMethod=post"/>
        <to uri="jms:queue:QnonSecure" pattern="InOut" />
        <enrich uri="direct:securityApp"/>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${header.myHeader} == "SECURE"</simple>
                <to uri="jms:queue:QSecure" pattern="InOut" />
                <to uri="direct:actionApp" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <!-- handle non valid requests -->
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Steps:

1. The browser sends a POST request to the Camel `restlet` component. This could be done via JavaScript, a link and/or just a ordinary submit button.
2. The body is sent to `jms:queue:QnonSecure`. As we use the `InOut` pattern, this is done in a synchronous manner and the response is fetched.
3. The response of `jms:queue:QnonSecure` is sent to `direct:securityApp` where the credentials are tested. If they are correct, the header `myHeader` is set to `SECURE` (or any other value).
4. In the `choice` statement, `myHeader` is tested. In the secure case, `jms:queue:QSecure` and finally `direct:actionApp` is invoked.

Comment: Thanks Peter. You seem very knowledgeable about camel and activemq. Did you learn mostly through practice or is there another quick way to get familiar? The 1st option makes more sense to my less seasoned camel mind. What if testQsource doesn't exist? How do I send the input from the browser into testQdestination? Also, where in my code do I call the security app between the testQdestination and securityQ?

Comment: @user3734863 If `testQsource` does not exist, it is created by ActiveMQ. Use Camel's `ProducerTemplate` (see http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) for sending JMS messages. However, if you need synchronous feedback, don't use JMS at all. I guess in your case this would make everything a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks again. How can I send data/messages from my browser into testQdestination then send the data/messages in testQdestination through the security app and into Qsecure before I send them to the actionApp?

Comment: That is fantastic and makes a lot more sense to me. Thanks you so much for all of your time. The enrich is a big part of what I was missing.